# On Kusama, how many democratic proposals can be submitted in each referendum period?

Tags: democratic

On Kusama, how many democratic proposals can be submitted in each referendum period?
and what config on ksm runtime?
I find here are two referendum on kusama.
My proposal is urgent. What should I do?
I can only submit democratic proposals, and I am very worried that my proposals will be crowded out by parliamentary proposals, because I have very important proposals to submit.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every 7 days, a new referendum will come up for a vote, assuming there is at least one proposal in one of the queues. There is a queue for Council-approved proposals ("External Queue") and a queue for publicly submitted proposals ("Proposals"). The referendum to be voted upon alternates between the top proposal in the two queues.

This mean that in the current design, only one referendum will be voted per launch period (7 days). However, if the Technical Committee decides to fast-track a proposal in external queue given its urgency, more than one proposal can be voted at the same time - as you can see on your screenshot (the added proposals originate from council as external motions).

It is true that if you submit in public queue you will need to wait for your proposal to be seconded first, then voted (7 days) then enacted (7 more days). A way to speed this up, and if your proposal is pertinent to the vote of the community, is to request Council to take into account your proposal for submission: any councillor will be able to open an external motion, work with TC on fast-tracking (if an emergency) to then pass it to vote by the community.

If you need assistance, feel free to contact me on Element: @raul.rtti:matrix.parity.io